# Capture newline from a textarea input

Tags: php, html

I have a textarea form in my html. If the user hits enter between 2 sentences that data should be carried over to my PHP.

Currently if the user enters:

```
Apple
Google
MS
```

and my PHP code is:

```
$str = $_POST["field"];

echo $str;
```

I get

```
Apple Google MS
```

as the output. I want output to be like this

```
Apple
Google
MS
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) instead:

```
echo nl2br($str);
```

Comment: Even better. Didn't know there was a built-in function dedicated to this.

Answer (score 3):

The newlines should be included in the string that you get from `$_POST["field"]`. However, if you then use that string as output in HTML, newlines will be treated as whitespace. To force the line breaks, use `preg_replace("/\n/", "<br />", $str)`.

Comment: That preg will fail (no delimiter), also why not just `str_replace()`?

Comment: True - fixed that. And your answer is better anyway. However, explaining the cause might help understanding the fix better.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you echo it it's being displayed as HTML. A `\n` character is interpreted as a space. If you view the source you'll see your desired output.

To convert `\n` to `<br>` use:

```
echo nl2br( $str );
```