# User Textarea line Breaks

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capture newline from a textarea input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844465/capture-newline-from-a-textarea-input)

I have a text area where a user adds  paragraphs. It is then displayed on the about page of the site. Is the a script which can maintain the formatting of the user input such as line breaks without displaying those tags?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you want to replace line breaks with <br />? nl2br()

Comment: i'd recommend adding htmlspeicalchars to replace html code and special characters, and stripslashes to remove slashes when saving the data to database. eg: nl2br(htmlspecialchars($str))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nl2br: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php