# Force Line Break In Text Area Form Field

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, directory, textarea

I have a front facing user input form for a directory and have a textarea box where users enter their address details.  If they press enter on keyboard and enter their address on multiple lines it still prints out online as one long line.

http://ilovestaffordshire.co.uk/listing/car-finance-net/

How can i force it to show on separate lines, so is more visually pleasing and easier to read?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture newline from a textarea input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844465/capture-newline-from-a-textarea-input)

Comment: What does that URL have to do with the question?

Comment: the url is showing the page which i want to edit, showing the address all on one line when i want it on multiple lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, lines must be separated with `<br />` to be printed as multiple lines. If the lines are printed in the source as separate lines, they are on a line separated with a whitespace.
Search newlines and replace with `<br />`. Or print within `<textarea></textarea>` and disable edit. Within `<textarea></textarea>` lines are displayed just as in the source.